# insert in next line python

Tags: python, sql, pandas

```
########################################################################################################################
#  Autor YURY ROGENS
#  GOOGLE SHEETS INTEGRAÇÃO PLANILHA
########################################################################################################################

from pyparsing import col
import pypyodbc as odbc # pip install pypyodbc
import pandas as pd # pip install pandas
from google_apis import create_service
import os.path
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


"""
CONEXÃO DE BANCO
"""

class DatabaseManager:
    def __init__(self, server_name, database_name):
        self.server_name = server_name
        self.database_name = database_name
        self._conn = None
        
     
    def initialize_connection(self):
        try:
            server = '192.168.102.4'
            database = 'CRM'
            username = 'crm'
            password = 'Sql123$$'
            driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
            self._conn = odbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
            
            print('Connection created successfully')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            self._conn = None

    def run_query(self, sql_statement):
        if self._conn is None:
            print('Connection is absent.')
            return
        
        cursor = self._conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql_statement)

        columns = tuple(col[0] for col in cursor.description)
        recordset = cursor.fetchall()
        return columns, recordset
        

    @property
    def connection(self):
        return self._conn


# Connect to Google Sheets Document
CLIENT_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
API_NAME = 'sheets'
API_VERSION = 'v4'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
GOOGLE_SHEETS_ID = '1nFC9Q9TqdatLrDSA48uW2dqQuYT7YALXWjd0vmGZuqk'

service = (CLIENT_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
#service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=CLIENT_FILE)

# Connect To Database
SERVER_NAME = '192.168.102.4'
DATABASE_NAME = 'CRM'
USERNAME = 'crm'
PASSWORD = 'Sql123$$'
DRIVER = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'

dbManager = DatabaseManager(SERVER_NAME, DATABASE_NAME)
dbManager.initialize_connection()

sql_query = ( "SELECT TOP 1 "
"NOME = B.A1_NOME, CPF = B.A1_CGC, "
"'E-MAIL' = CASE WHEN LEN(ISNULL(CC.CLIEMAIL, '')) > 5 THEN CC.CLIEMAIL "
"WHEN LEN(ISNULL(DD.CLIEXTEMAIL2, '')) > 5 THEN DD.CLIEXTEMAIL2 "
"ELSE B.A1_EMAIL COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN END, "
"DDD = CASE WHEN LEN(ISNULL(CC.CLIDDDCELULAR, '')) > 0 THEN CC.CLIDDDCELULAR "
"WHEN LEN(ISNULL(DD.CLIEXTDDDCELULAR2, '')) > 0 THEN DD.CLIEXTDDDCELULAR2 "
"ELSE B.A1_DDD COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN END, "
"CELULAR = CASE WHEN LEN(ISNULL(CC.CLICELULAR, '')) > 5 THEN CC.CLICELULAR "
"WHEN LEN(ISNULL(DD.CLIEXTCELULAR2, '')) > 5 THEN DD.CLIEXTCELULAR2 "
"ELSE B.A1_TEL COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN END, "
"DATACADASTRO = CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(DAY,((ASCII(SUBSTRING(A1_USERLGI,12,1))-50)*100+(ASCII(SUBSTRING(A1_USERLGI,16,1))-50)),'19960101'),112), "
"ANIVERSARIO = CASE WHEN LEN(B.A1_DTNASC) > 5 THEN B.A1_DTNASC "
"ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CC.CLIDTANASCIMENTO, 112) END, "
"ENDERECO = B.A1_END, "
"DOCUMENTO = A.L1_DOC, "
"CODIGOPRODUTO = E.L2_PRODUTO, "
"QUANTIDADE = E.L2_QUANT, "
"VALORUNITARIO = E.L2_VRUNIT, "
"VALORPEDIDO = E.L2_VLRITEM, "
"DATAPEDIDO = A.L1_DTLIM, "
"LOJA = A.L1_FILIAL, "
"CODVENDEDOR = A.L1_VEND, VENDEDOR = D.A3_NOME, "
"PDV = A.L1_PDV "
"FROM "
"[192.168.102.6].DBTOTVS12.dbo.SL1010 A, [192.168.102.6].DBTOTVS12.dbo.SA3010 D, "
"[192.168.102.6].DBTOTVS12.dbo.SL2010 E, "
"[192.168.102.6].DBTOTVS12.dbo.SA1010 B LEFT OUTER JOIN CLIENTES CC ON LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(B.A1_CGC))) > 1 AND CONVERT(DECIMAL(14, 0), LTRIM(RTRIM(B.A1_CGC))) = CC.CLICPFCNPJ                                          LEFT OUTER JOIN CLIENTESEXTENSAO DD ON CC.CLICODIGO = DD.CLICODIGO "
"WHERE "
"A.L1_CLIENTE = B.A1_COD "
"AND A.L1_CLIENTE <> '000000001' "
"AND A.L1_DTLIM >= '20210101' "
"AND A.L1_SITUA = 'OK' "
"AND A.L1_FILIAL = E.L2_FILIAL "
"AND A.L1_NUM = E.L2_NUM "
"AND A.L1_PDV = E.L2_PDV "
"AND A.L1_DOC = E.L2_DOC "
"AND E.L2_VEND = D.A3_COD "
"AND E.L2_FILIAL = D.A3_FILIAL "
"AND A.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "
"AND B.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "
"AND D.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "
"AND E.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "
"ORDER BY L1_DTLIM " )

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
#SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = '1nFC9Q9TqdatLrDSA48uW2dqQuYT7YALXWjd0vmGZuqk'
#SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'Dados!A1:P1000'

creds = None
 
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
   creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
   # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
       creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
       flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
       'client_secret.json', SCOPES)
       creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
       # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
       token.write(creds.to_json())

    
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

# Pegar informação de planilha
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId='1nFC9Q9TqdatLrDSA48uW2dqQuYT7YALXWjd0vmGZuqk',
                            range='A1:P1000').execute()
values = result.get('values', [])
#print(values)

columns, recordset = dbManager.run_query(sql_query)

#clear data
#service.spreadsheets().values().clear(spreadsheetId='1nFC9Q9TqdatLrDSA48uW2dqQuYT7YALXWjd0vmGZuqk',
#    range='Dados'
#).execute()

# Inserir Informação
if len('A2')!=0:
    print('celula NÃO VAZIA')
else: len('A2') + 1

request = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
    spreadsheetId='1nFC9Q9TqdatLrDSA48uW2dqQuYT7YALXWjd0vmGZuqk',
    valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED',
    range='Dados!A2',
    body={
        'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
        'values': recordset
    }
).execute()

# Inserir coluna
service.spreadsheets().values().update(
    spreadsheetId='1nFC9Q9TqdatLrDSA48uW2dqQuYT7YALXWjd0vmGZuqk',
    valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED',
    range='Dados!A1',
    body={
        'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
        'values': [columns]
    }
).execute()
```

When running the program it imports directly, but when I run it again it overwrites the information in the worksheet. I want to complement it by adding in the next 24hrs in 24hrs

Comment: To clarify, is this what you want?: 

The program should check if it wrote data in the past 24 hours. If the program has written data in the last 24 hours (ex. 10 hours ago it wrote data), it won't do anything at this time. If, however, it has been 24 hours or more, it will continue as normal and overwrite the information in the worksheet.


Is my understanding correct?

Comment: is incorrect, the program will run once and fill the cells in excel, next time it should check the filled lines and not fill them, example filled up to line 100, next time run the program fill from line 101 not letting you fill in the 100 for reasons of having already filled it out every 24 hours

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the program should run once until a certain line and then when run again on the next empty line